# How to find the ParentComboBox of a ComboBoxItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

How can I get the ParentComboBox of an ComboBoxItem?

I would like to close an open ComboBox if the *Insert*-Key is pressed:

```
 var focusedElement = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
 if (focusedElement is ComboBox)
 {
     var comboBox = focusedElement as ComboBox;
     comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = !comboBox.IsDropDownOpen;
 }
 else if (focusedElement is ComboBoxItem)
 {
     var comboBoxItem = focusedElement as ComboBoxItem;
     var parent = comboBoxItem.Parent; //this is null
     var parent = comboBoxItem.ParentComboBox; //ParentComboBox is private
     parent.IsDropDownOpen = !parent.IsDropDownOpen;
 }
```

It looks like there's no straight forward solution for this problem..

Comment: The solution of Thomas leads me to the following solution:

var parent = comboBoxItem.FindAncestor<ItemsPresenter>(); //Not ComboBox!
var comboBox = parent.TemplatedParent as ComboBox;

The link between ComboBoxItem and ComboBox can be made using the ItemsPresenter.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It also solved the connection between a ListBoxItem and its ListBox the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you want to retrieve an ancestor of a specific type. To do that, I often use the following method :

```
public static class DependencyObjectExtensions
{

    public static T FindAncestor<T>(this DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        return obj.FindAncestor(typeof(T)) as T;
    }

    public static DependencyObject FindAncestor(this DependencyObject obj, Type ancestorType)
    {
        var tmp = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
        while (tmp != null && !ancestorType.IsAssignableFrom(tmp.GetType()))
        {
            tmp = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(tmp);
        }
        return tmp;
    }

}
```

You can use it as follows :

```
var parent = comboBoxItem.FindAncestor<ComboBox>();
```

Comment: I think the usage should be as follow:
    var parent = comboBoxItem.FindAncestor<ComboBox>();

This ends in an endless while-loop: tmp is always a StackPanel

Comment: No endless while-loop anymore:
tmp = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(tmp); //Instead of GetParent(obj)..

But still: null, no ComboBox...

Answer (score 0):

As H.B. [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5801401/5198722) you also can use

```
var parent = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(comboBoxItem) as ComboBox;
```