# Set ComboBox text by clicking on ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, text, combobox

I have a CustomComboBoxItem which is derived from ComboBoxItem

```
public class CustomComboBoxItem : ComboBoxItem {

    ...

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
    }

}
```

I need to set the text of the ComboBox by cliking on the CustomComboBoxItem. I don't want to use the SelectionChanged event on the ComboBox itself because I want it to be set by mouse click.

I really don't have any idea what I should do about it. Please share your ideas with me. thanks a million.

**Edit**

I have a CustomComboBox which has a TextBox in the ControlTemplate. and in the GetContainerForItemOverride overriden method:

```
protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
{
    return new CustomComboBoxItem();
}
```

Comment: sorry it is all in code-behind.

Comment: can you try to find Parent? I'll do a test later to see if it possible...

Comment: Oh that sounds a goon idea. I've found an article about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399967/how-to-find-the-parentcombobox-of-a-comboboxitem I'm going to test it.

Comment: Why don't you just use the default `ComboBox` functionality??? There's a `TextBox` in the default `ControlTemplate` and it is automatically set to the selected item too.

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem with this line of code in CustomComboBoxItem

```
var parent = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(this) as CustomComboBox;
```